# Regular Expression Regex for Format MMYY for current year (e.g) 19 and future years in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I need a regular expression to be used in credit card form
the rule is simple, the format must be `MMYY`.

I could achieve that with this regular expression.

```
/^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\d{2}$/
```

Now am researching to apply validation to make **YY** 19 for the current year
and in future years.

Maybe its hard to make it dynamic, but i can replace the string 19 from
current year in javascript, so now I just want it fixed for 19 and above.

**Example of valid MMYY:**

0126

1220

0119

**Example of In Valid MMYY**

0101

1111

1218

Here is reference of what i have now
[Example shared for my reg exp looks like](https://regex101.com/r/cfMAHq/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a year for which that year and future years should pass, it'd be a bit tedious to dynamically construct such a regular expression. Consider using a capture group instead, and then just check whether the captured YY is greater than or equal to the limit:

```
const yearLimit = 19; // or pass this as an argument if you want

const re = /^(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])(\d{2})$/;
const match = str.match(re);
if (!match) {
  return false;
}
const year = Number(match[1]);
return year >= yearLimit;
```

```js
const validate = (str) => {
  const yearLimit = 19; // or pass this as an argument if you want

  const re = /^(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])(\d{2})$/;
  const match = str.match(re);
  if (!match) {
    return false;
  }
  const year = Number(match[1]);
  return year >= yearLimit;
};

console.log(
  validate('1234'),
  validate('1212')
);
```

`^(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])(\d{2})$` means

- `^` - Match start of string
- `(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])` - Match 01-12: either

  - `0[1-9]` - Leading `0`, followed by a number 1 to 9, or
  - `1[0-2]` - Leading `1`, followed by a number 0 to 2
- `(\d{2})` - Match and capture any two digits
- `$` - Match end of string

Comment: i believe it fails on 0101 check your reg expression, i tested here https://regex101.com/r/sPaRXh/1

Comment: The testing against the year is done *after* the pattern matches, in the test of the extracted capture group. If you put `0101` into the snippet, `verify` will return `false`, as desired.

Comment: i loved your style, here is another test too https://codepen.io/shareefhiasat/pen/qBBWBKX

Comment: can you improve answer by explaining the regular expression, as this what started this question....

Comment: @CertainPerformance it should be ^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-1])$

Answer (score 0):

Below code will work if you want to solve it by regex only.

```js
const currentYear = 19;
const currentDecade = currentYear/10;
const unitPlaceCurrentYear = currentYear%10;
regex_string = `^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])(1[${unitPlaceCurrentYear}-9]|[${currentDecade+1}-9][0-9])$`

var re = new RegExp(regex_string);

inputs = ['0126','1220','0119','0101','1111','1218'];
inputs.map((str) => {
  let match = str.match(re);
  if (match) console.log('matched: ' + str);
  else console.log('Did not match: ' + str);
});
```

Comment: I can't get this to work, heres the regex output string "^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])(1[3-9]|[3.3-9][0-9])$"

Answer (score 0):

Here is the dynamic solution for your answer

```js
    var date = new Date()
    var a = date.getFullYear().toString().substr(2,2).split('')
    var monthRegex = "(0[1-9]|1[0-2])"
    var yearRegex1 = "([" + a[0] + "-9][" + a[1] + "-9])"
    var yearRegex2 = "([" + (parseInt(a[0], 10) + 1) + "-9][0-9])"

    var regex2 = new RegExp("^" + monthRegex + yearRegex1 + "|" + yearRegex2 + "$");
    
    console.log(regex2.test('1218'))
    console.log(regex2.test('1219'))
    console.log(regex2.test('1239'))
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Actually [@CertainPerformance](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9515207/certainperformance) is incorrect. It should be: `^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-1])$`

```js
const validate = (str) => {
  const yearLimit = 19; // or pass this as an argument if you want

  const re = /^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-1])$/;
  const match = str.match(re);
  //Match return Array(3) [ "0130", "01", "30" ]
  if (!match) {
    return false;
  }
  const year = Number(match[2]);
  return year >= yearLimit;
};

console.log(
  validate('0121'), //January 2021
  validate('1212'), //December 2012
  validate('1132'), //November 2032
  validate('0136'), //January 2036
);
```

Comment: Please share what 's wrong with the @CertainPerformance answer... What does your regex ?

Comment: Also, when i'm testing '0126' it return false or this is supposed to be valid

Comment: @SioGabx That's literally not true at all I just tested it and '0126' passes. You're doing something wrong. As to what it does -- figure it out. Go to regex101.com

Comment: Small typo, I meant '0136' (and it doesn't work on regex101).
If fact, your regex doesn't work at all after 0132 (January 2032)